# Por qué los programas C++ que uso API Windows abren una terminal

Tags: c++, api, windows

Me gustaría saber por qué razón y como evitarlo, los programas ejecutables de c++ que creo con g++ abren obligatoriamente una terminal para ejecutarse.

Este es mi ejemplo:

```
// Se incluye la librería para windows
#include <windows.h>

// Declaramos la Función Principal
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, 
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PSTR szCmdLine,
                    int iCmdShow)
{   
    // Utiliza la Api para desplegar una Ventana como Mensaje
    MessageBox (NULL, 
                TEXT ("Hola Mundo en Windows"), 
                TEXT ("HelloMsg"), 
                MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE);
    
    // Finaliza
    return 0 ;
}
```

Si compilo lo anterior así: `g++ main.cpp -o main.exe`

Al ejecutar el main.exe, me abre una terminal de Windows y ahí aparece el MessageBox.
Como evitar que abra la terminal y solo aparezca el messagebox?
Gracias

Comment: Usa el [*flag* `-mwindows`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Windows-Options.html) al compilar: `g++ main.cpp -mwindows -o main.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se debe usar el flag [-mwindows](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Windows-Options.html) al compilar:

```
g++ main.cpp -mwindows -o main.exe
```

Al compilar con -mwindows, ya no se genera la terminal.

Esto fue sugerido por [@Trauma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/19610/trauma)